# The argument type '_PostCreateRoute' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Map>

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a social networking site using flutter . This is a feed related page which stores if there are feed available for the user or not and if there are feed it shows it . I am using asynchronous method for action during feed update so while creating on-pressed it is showing an error while creating PostCreateRoute object that the argument type '_PostCreateRoute' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route'.  and I am new to flutter and if someone can help me out it would be great .

```
 class _FeedActionButtonState extends State<FeedActionButton> {
 BuildContext _context;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    return new FloatingActionButton(
    child: new Icon(Icons.add, color:Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
    onPressed: onPressed,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white);
 }
    onPressed() async{
    Mappost=await
    Navigator.of(_context).push(new_PostCreateRoute(_context));
    if (post!=null &&widget.onPosted!=null){
        this .widget.onPosted(post)
      } 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing `_PostCreateRoute()` as an argument to the push function which only accepts the arguments of type `Route()`.

You first need to wrap your class in a route object like `MaterialPageRoute (Android)` or `CupertinoPageRoute (iOS)`.

You can try something like:

```
Navigator.push(_context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext _context) => _PostCreateRoute(_context)));
```

Make sure you import `material.dart` or `cupertino.dart` depending on which route type you go with.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledgment . But still it is showing the error of error: The return type '_PostCreateRoute' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure.It is suggesting to type cast to route . Could you help me out how to do it !

Comment: Could you let me know the return type _PostCreateRoute? And perhaps what exactly it does? It will help me in understanding what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: See I am getting this error :The argument type '#lib1::_PostCreateRoute' can't be assigned to the parameter type '#lib2::Route<dart.core::Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'.
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to '#lib2::Route<dart.core::Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'.
        await Navigator.of(_context).push(new _PostCreateRoute(_context));

Comment: I am trying to run a github repository for some learning . I dont know exactly how would this class would contribute but wanna know so if it works then i could learn a bit